# Bulma переопределить css

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, frontend

Доброго времени суток.

Верстаю с использованием css фреймворка Bulma.
Возникла проблема со стилями, а именно в моем файле main.css.
Я прописываю:

```
.main-text {
  …
  color: white !important;
}
```

Однако это не помогает, и текст держится стилей фреймворка.

Помогите переопределить стили.

Comment: создайте свой класс со своими стилями

Comment: так это мой класс, дело в теге h1

Answer (score 1):

Использовал такой костыль:
    `< style="color: white; font-size: 32px;">`
помогло

Comment: У тебя стили с фреймворка могут загружаться после основного файла со стилями, проверь.